# How to layer one div between two that hover?

Tags: css, html

On a sort of navigation bar, I have a div `one` that acts like one category on the nav bar, and another div that has related links for that category. There's one longer div, with the same width, that acts as the background for the bar. I have it so that normally, the div `two` rests below the related div `one`, and when you hover over div `one`, div `two` pops out to the right of it. Then, when you move your mouse away from either of the divs, div `two` goes back below the div `one`.

The problem that I need to fix is that I need the long background div to stay under div `one`, and on top of div `two`, so div `two` is hidden until it slides out from under the background div, and to the right of the related div `one`.

I've tried using `z-index`, but it doesn't seem to have an effect. And if I move the order of elements around, it just messes it up more.

EDIT: Here's the link to the jsfiddle-  http://jsfiddle.net/FEKfK/ , I added background colors on the divs to make it easier to see.

What I need to do, is get the black background bar to be over the red bar, the one that moves, and still have the blue div one stay on top. That way, the red bar is hidden until you hover over div one.

What I have in HTML:

```
<div id="behind"></div>
<div id="one"><p id="group">Group 1</p>
    <div id="two">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="example.html">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="example.html">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="example.html">Link 3</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#one {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    top:10px;
    line-height:27px;
    display:absolute;
    margin:15px 0 0 10px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:3;
}

#two {
    width:120px;
    height:100;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inherit;
    line-height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease; 
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease; 
    transition:all .5s ease;
    z-index:1;
}

#one:hover > #two {
    display:block;
    left:105px;
    top:0px;
}

#behind {
    width:115px;
    height:444px;
    margin-top:7px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: happy to say about [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) there you can paste your code and make it as scenario and post the link of fiddle here in your question that make your question clear.. :)

Comment: @VivekVikranth  here you go, I'll also put it in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/FEKfK/

Comment: Why not using little javascript to toggle links div only on hover on category div ?

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj I don't know javascript well, and this is for a web design class that's only been using HTML and CSS so far. I could use js if I absolutely needed to, but I'm trying to avoid it where I can, and I've already got the position and animation set exactly how I want them. I just need background div layering to get right

Comment: Check out http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-drop-down-menu this one did the same thing you are trying on. You should get some idea.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj is there something wrong with my browser? Whenever I open that lab, all there is is the 4 menu items in the gray bar, and the arrow points down when you hover over Item 2. I see the transitions in the CSS, but there's nothing happening

Comment: Its working on Chrome and Firefox on may machine. On hover on second menu a sub menu comes. Try if you can on latest browsers.

Comment: Oh, it works in Firefox but not in Chrome for me. I'll try implementing this into my site later, and see if it works. Thanks!